# Подключение dll

Tags: applet, java, dll

Доброго времени суток! Можно ли сделать, чтобы `dll` библиотеки искались на хосте сайта, а не только в `windows/system32`?

Comment: Не в windows/system32 клиента? Т.е. Вы хотите подгружать dll с сайта? Однако.

Comment: @alexlz, посмотрите на предыдущие вопросы ТС'а. Он пытается сделать апплет, в котором использует нативные библиотеки. Но у него не получается собрать апплет так, чтобы он работал в том числе на компьютерах, на которых этих библиотек нет. Как временное решение он положил dll'ки в system32, а теперь, видимо, вплотную подошёл к проблеме их загрузки на компьютере клиента.

Answer (score 1):

Загрузка библиотеки производится через `System.loadLibrary()`, закавыка заключается в том, что библиотеки будут искаться в пути заданном в свойстве `System.getProperty("java.library.path")`, который в свою очередь задается 1 раз при запуске JVM, а на лету System свойства JVM насколько я помню не меняются...

Так что единственный способ который я вижу это на клиентской машине запускать JVM с ключом типа: `-Djava.library.path=mypath`

Comment: на лету это свойство изменить можно, только все равно не работает, если удаленный адрес прописать

Comment: Так скачивайте библиотеки в данный директорий (по тому же http/get) и запускайте с локальной dll. Решение убогое, но и сама задача -- весьма специфична.